# Everything is ok but it says Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable: categories

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
//controller:
private function getAll() {

    $data['categories'] = $this->registrant_model->getAllDepartment();
    $this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/registrant', $data);

}

//model:
public function getAllDepartment() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('patient_db');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}


//view:
<?php foreach($categories as $c):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $c['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c['phone'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $c['name'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

this is the code. every time it says undefined variable and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach. please help

Comment: Where is the variable $categories defined? I think you mean: $categories = $this->registrant_model->getAllDepartment();

Comment: I suppose you meant to type `$data['categories']` instead of `$categories`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: yes you have to pass $data to the view.so you can access $categories from view

Comment: thats not working man.
it says
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Seems like the OP fixed the issue, looking at the [last edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38185217/revisions) of this question

Comment: @Timothy not fixed

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `$data` array to view from controller

```
$data['categories'] = $this->registrant_model->getAllDepartment();
$this->load->view('SystemAdminUser/registrant', $data);// pass $data to view
```

Comment: `print_r($data)` in controller and post its value